# ActiveMQ Request/Reply Pattern : which approach to follow in below considered good performance?

Tags: java, session, design-patterns, activemq-classic, synchronous

Below are the two approach which am using, Please help me to understand which one is better! Its a synchronous process.

Approach 1: (Not closing any connection object)

> Created connectionfactory in below class and maintaining pool of that class

ConnectionPool.java (maintaining a pool of different producers with broker url)

```
private static Map<String, Producer> producers
public static ProducerPool getInstance() {
        if(INSTANCE==null){
            producers = Maps.newConcurrentMap();
            INSTANCE= new ProducerPool();
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
```

Producer.java (all the connection objects created here)

```
private ActiveMQConnection connection;
private ActiveMQSession session;
private MessageProducer producer;
return consumer.receive(5000);
```

So if 100 req comes also it will maintain only one connection , producer, session.

Approach 2:

> (Closing all connection,session,producer per request and not a singleton)

Approach 3:

> (Keeping only connection alive and closing session and producer per each req and recreate the same which is closed per request)

Which approach will suite for more performance? in request reply pattern maximum level which one(connection r session r producer) we can reuse?
Had a glance at : (can anyone help with a example how to use it!)

> PooledConnectionFactory

Please help which one should follow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really cannot be answered without doing a performance test on the same  system(s) configuration that will be used in production. There are too many variables in determining what the best performance will be. For example, to determine just the broker configuration you would need to validate the following:

- Number of CPUs?
- Amount of RAM?
- Number of Network Card interfaces?
- Number of disk mounts used for storage backend?
- Number of queues used?
- Number of producers?
- Number of consumers?
- Size of messages?
- Message volume (msg/s)?

The Best Practice for messaging is to *not* pre-tune. Most customers I go into do not actually have high message volume. Try simple single connection, single session and single producer first. If it meets your performance requirement, than focus on getting HA and monitoring metrics squared away. Getting those right has a much higher return on the investment of your time and lead to a more stable messaging platform vs trying to tweak out another 5-10% performance boost.

Remember: most messaging systems are going to be limited by the speed of the disk of the broker, so caching objects on the client side only benefits in certain edge case scenarios.